# Why jQuery $('#form').submit(); works perfectly BUT Not $('#form').submit(function(){...});?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When I try to submit a form with jQuery, a simple

```
$('#form').submit();
```

works perfectly but

```
$('#form').submit(function(){...});
```

is purely and simply ignored.
No error message, no nothing.
It move on and proceed the rest of my code just fine.

The closer issue I've found here is this one:
[JQuery form submit with function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011272/jquery-form-submit-with-function-not-working)
It works better but the submit() reload the page and cancel the benefit of the Ajax.
So unfortunatly, it doesn't works for me :(

Here is my entire code (I reduced the true project to the simplest for test purpose) :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>please help</title>
    <link href="../htdocs/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<form id="myForm" method="post">
    <input name="key01" type="checkbox" id="key01" checked>
    <input name="key02" type="checkbox" id="key02" checked>
    <input name="key03" type="checkbox" id="key03" checked>
    <input name="key04" type="checkbox" id="key04" checked>
    <input name="key05" type="checkbox" id="key05" checked>

    <div id="testBtn">test submit</div>
</form>

<div id="resultDisplay"></div>

<script src="../htdocs/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="../htdocs/js/icheck.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#testBtn').click(function () {
            console.log('click out');
            $('#myForm').submit(function () {
                console.log('click In');
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'myResult.php',
                    data: $(this).serialize()
                }).done(function (data) {
                    console.log('data back');
                    $("#resultDisplay").html(data);
                }).fail(function () {
                    alert("error");
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The only console.log I have is the first one outside the submit function.
I tried with alert instead, with get method, with differents jQuery versions on Apache and nginx server...
it's all the same :'(

PHP : 5.6.23
jQuery 2.2.4 (several versions tested)

Please help, I'm desperate :(

Comment: Do you know what the difference between `submit()` and `submit(function(){})` is?

Comment: Well... I know it now, and probably will never forget it :)

Comment: Thank everybody for your answers, it was helpful and I'll do better next time ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually $('#form') returns an array and the properly way of performing it is by specifying what array's item will perform the given function:

```js
$("#form")[0].submit(function(){
    //do the stuff
})
```